# How to load csv files into DStreams as a batch?

Tags: python, text, pyspark, spark-streaming, batch-processing

I am totally new to the topic DStreams - the basic abstraction of spark streaming which is used to receive stream of data as a batch. What I am trying to do is, I have a text file containing more than 1000 records. I need to send the text file to DStreams for stream processing. For that, I wrote a code in python that creates a DStream and I pass the path of the text file into DStream with 10 seconds interval(batch). I didn't get any data inside the batch. Here is the code,

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("PysparkStreaming").getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)   #Batch duration 10 seconds
type(ssc)
lines = ssc.textFileStream('/home/Downloads/Dataset/data.txt')  #create DStream
type(lines)

        
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))\
               .map(lambda x: (x, 1))\
               .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
type(counts)
counts.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I got the output like,

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-10-02 13:57:40
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-10-02 13:57:50
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-10-02 13:58:00
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-10-02 13:58:10
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-10-02 13:58:20
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-10-02 13:58:30
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-10-02 13:58:40
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2020-10-02 13:58:50
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
```

What I need is, inside the time interval, the data from the text file must display.But it doesn't show anything in between the batch. Please, I need your help to get out of this issue... Anyone tell me what I have to do to get the data as a batch. I need the code in python. Thank u.

Comment: why do you need Spark Streaming for that case?

Comment: Because, I am working with Apache spark for processing real time data.. So that I need  DStreams to receive text file as a batch (interval) and send it to RDD. RDD receives batch from DStreams and send it for spark stream engine for further processing like analysis of data... To do all this, I need DStreams as the basic thing to send batch of data. My aim is to use Apache spark for processing as it supports in-memory.

Comment: if it's a new project, please seriously consider use Structured Streaming instead of Streaming with DStreams